# Search range of strings for a word

Tags: excel, function, vba, range

I'm trying to write a function in VBA for excel. =findval("Word",B:B), I want to search the Range B:B(these are short strings) for a word. If the word exists return Yes or No. So far I can search a string for a word but I can't get this to work over a range.

Comment: Since you have mentioned vba, would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10986326/findnext-failing-after-a-find-function-excel-vba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will a worksheet function suffice?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"*"&"Word"&"*"),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: This would work perfect, is there a way to ignore blank spaces?