# How to end this kind of do loop?

Tags: excel, vba

Good day,

I'm trying to end the loop I've done but not sure what should I enter. Once a value has been offset, that's it, I want to end the loop. Sometimes the value to find is more than one, and total of all data in the excel is until row 1500.

Please help me. Here's the code I've used below.

```
Sub third()

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1500").End(xlUp))

    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("31184", LookIn:=xlValues)
       If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Offset(0, 8).Value = "INPUT A NAME"
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: use `If Not c Is Nothing Then c.Offset(0, 8).Value = "INPUT A NAME": Exit Do`

Comment: So, even if there's more than one "31184" you just want to deal with the first one found? Or do you want to process all of them? If it's the first thing, then Gary's Student has an answer that works. If the second [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10988232/293078) should help.

Comment: Do you need to find and set value for all matches?

Comment: Thanks for the link Doug! I'll review that and see what I can incorporate on my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub third()
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A1500").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("31184", LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.Offset(0, 8).Value = "INPUT A NAME"
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: The exact answer I was looking for. Thank you Gary's Student!